# SQL: Incorrect Syntax Error, Stored Pocedure for Searching with Date of Birth

Tags: sql, search, syntax

I've been grappling with this error for two days now and am at my wits end.

There's a stored procedure on my database that does a search of the employee data on it. Whenever a user tries to search using the date of birth field, an error on the footer of the browser pops up. I've tried various solutions and finally come to an error which says:

> "Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
> Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
> 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Thu, 14 Nov 2013 05:06:57 UTC
>
> Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
> Incorrect syntax near '1982.03.26'. Line: 938 Char: 13 Code: 0 URI:
>
> Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
> Incorrect syntax near '1982.03.26'. Line: 938 Char: 13 Code: 0 URI:
> "

The Search Engine SQL syntax is as follows:

```
    IF @NAME <> 'NULL' SET @S = @S + 'E.ENAME LIKE ''%' + @Name + '%'' AND '
IF @ADdress <> 'NULL' SET @S = @S + '(PADDRESS LIKE ''%' + @ADdress + '%'' OR CADDRESS LIKE ''%' + @ADDRESS + '%'') AND '
IF @dob <> '1 JAN 1900' SET @S = @S + 'DOB ''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dob, 102) + ''' AND '
```

Any help is much appreciated -.-

Comment: If this is mssql please say so. Also I would recommend running the query on the DB rather than inside whatever web app this is... Then the database can give you a specific error message, not this vague one.

Comment: maybe try changing `'DOB '''` to `'DOB = '''`

Comment: @FaddishWorm, the OP is using WebMethods in asp.net webforms.  This is an uncaught exception that the user should now take more care in capturing within a try/catch block, so a cleaner error can be passed back...

Comment: asp.net should have been in the tags :P -- thats what I was trying to get at, exception model not throwing issues all the way up to UI layer so hard to debug... typical M$ developer :P ha ha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the equal sign.  This ad hoc query building invites SQL injection, though.

```
IF @dob <> '1 JAN 1900' SET @S = @S + 'DOB = ''' -- <-- this equal sign was missing after DOB
+  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dob, 102) + ''' AND '
```